# When I remove elements is there a difference between layout.children.clear() and layout.children.remove()?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have used C# to add elements to my layout that has a name of detailsLayout. I add about 20 grids elements and inside each of those are more elements:

Now I want to delete those elements. Is there a difference between these two ways:

```
detailsLayout.Children.Remove();
```

and

```
detailsLayout.Children.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't verify this but I could imagine the following. `Remove` is intended for removing 1 entry. By doing so, the remove will also call all kinds of events associated with the removal of one entry. Such as maybe updating the UI or triggering an event.

With `Clear`, all children are first removed and then all associated actions, like, again updating the UI or triggering an event, are done. Because it is apparent that you want to remove *all* the children since you are calling `Clear` the system can wait to trigger resulting actions until the operation is done.

In this case, it will mostly be a matter of performance. In the end, both will have the same result.